# API containing promised-mongo queries ending up with 504 error

Tags: mongodb, promise

I am using promised-mongo queries in my back end API to fetch some data from my database to front end. The API takes too long and finally finishes with 504 http error. Why is this happening?

Here is one such query

```
try {
    let query1;
    if(req.query.emailId=='')
        query1={};
    else
        query1={$or: [{'appActions.hubId' : {$in:hubIds}}, {'ruleActions.hubIds' : {$in:hubIds}}]};
    console.log('3');
    console.log('query1'+JSON.stringify(query1[0]));
    let size=await db.scene.count(query1);
    return size;
} catch (error) {
    reconnect(error);
}
```

Comment: try any basic query and check whether that works?

Comment: @Aky_0788 basic queries work, the problem is with promised queries. I want to use promised ones only.

Comment: I meant a simple promised query only

Comment: Isn't the above query simple? shall I have to try with out try, catch blocks?

Comment: *"I am using promised-mongo..."* Why? The native driver has supported promises "out of the box" for many releases. Simply use the native driver and not some other implementation with questionable support.

Comment: I will explore it. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native is this the native library? Can I use async await with this? Please help , I am new to all this stuff.